# gnu parallel: output each job to a different file

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I am trying to process so text files with `awk` using the `parallel` command as a shell script, but haven't been able to get it to output each job to a different file

If i try:

```
seq 10 | parallel awk \''{ if ( $5 > 0.4 ) print $2}'\' file{}.txt > file{}.out
```

It outputs to the file `file{}.out` instead of `file1.out`, `file2.out`, etc.

The tutorial and man pages also suggest that I could use `--files`, but it just prints to `stdout`:

```
seq 10 | parallel awk \''{ if ( $5 > 0.4 ) print $2}'\' file{}.txt --files file{}.out
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out I needed to quote out the redirect, because it was being processed outside of `parallel`:

```
seq 10 | parallel awk \''{...}'\' file{}.txt ">" file{}.out
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to introduce the entire parallel command inside double quotes:

`seq 10 | parallel " awk command > file{}.out "`

Although, sometimes is useful redirect the output to file and also to stdout. You can achieve that using `tee`. In this case, the command to be used could be:

`seq 10 | parallel " awk command | tee file{}.out "`

Answer (score 3):

`--results` is made for this:

```
seq 10 |
  parallel --results file{}.out awk \''{ if ( $5 > 0.4 ) print $2}'\' file{}.txt
```

It will also generate `file*.out.seq` (containing the sequence number) and `file*.out.err` (containing stderr).