# GNU parallel: output each job to a different file without pipes

Tags: gnu-parallel

> This question is very close to [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187834/gnu-parallel-output-each-job-to-a-different-file), but that answer is not
>   valid for me, I think due to my shell script does not work with pipes.

This is my multi-job command :

```
parallel "./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -t 15" ::: $(seq 0 2)
```

I would like output to something like:

```
file0.out
file1.out
file2.out
```

I don't know where should I put the **redirector** `>`.

I have tested with no luck:

```
parallel ./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -t 15 ">" file{}.out ::: $(seq 0 1)
parallel ./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -t 15 ::: $(seq 0 1) ">" file{}.out
```

My **script** works in this way:

```
./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -t 15 0
./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -t 15 1
./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -t 15 2
```

So output would go (for the above manual unparallelized example) to `file0.out`, `file1.out` and `file2.out`.

What is the correct way to redirect **each job** to a different file?

Further unsuccessful tests:

```
parallel --files file{}.out "./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -t 15" ::: $(seq 0 2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"my script works this way"*? What are the 0, 1 and 2 at the end?

Comment: Just the main parameter, @MarkSetchell. I would like this number to be the index. Modified original question to reflect.

Comment: I think you want `parallel ./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -t 15 {} ">" file{#}.out :::  0 1 2`

Comment: @MarkSetchell , your suggestion yields `/bin/bash: ./ClientesActives-AP-N.sh: No such file or directory` three times. Same on absolute path case for the `.sh` script.

Comment: My spanish spelling was rubbish, please try again. Also try using `parallel --dry-run` to see what it will do but without actually doing anything.

Comment: No problem, @MarkSetchell. Here it is: `/ClientesActives-AP-N.sh -t 15 > file1.out` (3 lines with `file2.out` and `file3.out`).

Comment: You have missed `{}` after `-t 15`

Comment: LOL. I am a complete idiot!. Excuse me, @MarkSetchell . The method seems to work fine, except for the creation of `file1.out`, 2 and 3 instead of `file0.out`, `file1.out` and `file2.out`. Anyway, it will enough with slight modifications on my script. Thanks a lot. You should write it down as an answer, and if possible expand about the meaning of that `{}`: why is it needed?

Comment: I found it: just removing the `#` solves the file number issue, @MarkSetchell.

Comment: Try changing `{#}` to `{}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find that the `--dry-run` option is a great way to debug **GNU Parallel** commands. Basically, it tells you what it would do without actually doing anything - it also saves me having to write a dummy *"ClientesActivos"* script and we all know how good my Spanish isn't ;-)

So, to your immediate question, if you try this, I think what it shows is what you want to do:

```
$ parallel --dry-run ./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -t 15 {} ">" file{}.out ::: {0..1}

./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -t 15 0 > file0.out
./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -t 15 1 > file1.out
```

Comment: Also have a look at --results: `parallel --results outdir ./ClientesActivos-AP-N.sh -t 15 {} ::: {0..1}` It might be a workable solution for the poster, too. But it does not do exactly what the poster asks for.